# All li from ul tag using beautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all li tags from specific ul using for loop but it is giving me so much trouble.
the ul tag can be seen here https://i.ibb.co/ynhHyBm/mal-link.png

Comment: Provide the link from where you are trying to extract the data

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video list is embedded within the page in Javascript. You can use `re`/`json` modules to load it:

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/1'
data = json.loads(re.search(r'videos: (\[.*\]),', requests.get(url).text).group(1))

# uncomment this to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for video in data:
    print(video['title'])
    print(video['thumbnail'])
    print('https://myanimelist.net' + video['episodeUrl'])
    print(BeautifulSoup(video['url'], 'html.parser').iframe['src'])
    print('-'*80)
```

Prints:

```
Return of the Hero
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire1-tmb/0ab1550fe9153139fe64312d95ae753b1554829384_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/1
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783080&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Human Monster
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3-tmb/ebe0faa7619d43e9f796219448fa08be1555390015_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/2
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783081&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Hunt Begins
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire2-tmb/161e6d5b8ac681036dd999638f6a156f1556015789_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/3
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783082&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Metal Bat
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4-tmb/e247142b17339cc973f87dc0111962341556597614_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/4
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783083&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Martial Arts Tournament
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3-tmb/7b2c351a0d834b578bcf40fe43f0b7941557224239_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/5
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783084&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Uprising of the Monsters
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4-tmb/8ecd3563ff013aa2fb527e57aa969ad01557803456_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/6
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783085&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class S Heroes
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4-tmb/f97132bc5df0d652457c44e0dd8701191558414332_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/7
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783086&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Strong Ones Fight Back
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire2-tmb/2d6573bd54cf1043cd261ae5b0e7cda91559064417_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/8
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783087&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Ultimate Dilemma
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire4-tmb/f288b5455dc251ddd1fd7658ce61fd3b1560216566_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/9
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783088&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Encircling Net of Justice
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3-tmb/0c8d6dee69ea8ccb5907bfaebe5873ec1560885135_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/10
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783089&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Everyone's Dignity
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire3-tmb/b06b7b6d6e1b4c3302b4e8d4245d45df1561436718_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/11
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783090&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cleaning Up the Disciple's Mess
https://img1.ak.crunchyroll.com/i/spire2-tmb/1c5e90d7d970ee9f96d6b2c7dd33acc01562086960_large.jpg
https://myanimelist.net/anime/34134/One_Punch_Man_2nd_Season/episode/12
https://www.crunchyroll.com/affiliate_iframeplayer?aff=af-12299-plwa&media_id=783091&video_format=0&video_quality=0&auto_play=0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you please tell how can i get image src which is present in li > a >img